# If option value is not available in the select form, show error

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if the title is not clear enough, here is the explaination :
I got a MYSQL Database named "perso", with "perso_name in it". The perso_name are the same as the values in my select form. Here is the HTML code :

```
<form method="post">
<select name="selectperso" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <option value="op1">Option1</option>
    <option value="op2">Option2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="validperso" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

Here is the PHP code :

```
 <?php 
$error = 0;
if (isset($_POST['validperso'])) {

    if ($error !== 0) {

        echo"<script>alert(\"Error\")</script>"; }

    else {

        echo "<script>alert(\"Working\")</script>"; 

    }

}
 ?>
```

Now, what i want to do is kinda tricky.

Let's say i have "op3" in my database, but the user can't have it. The problem is that the user can modify the value "op1" to "op3" and then he will have the op3. I want to make a condition which says "if the user select one of the "op" value available in the select, then it's ok. Else, error++."

Thanks for the help !

Comment: you need to check if a row exists

Comment: op3 does exist tho.

Comment: Then you need to check if user can use `op3`

Comment: he can use it, but only me can give the access to op3, he can't take it from the form.

Comment: So create some rules what user can and what cannot. And check his input against these rules. By rules I mean some function / if statements / whatever that can be translated to a code.

Comment: Well if there is no better ways i guess i'll use this, thanks you :)

Comment: What else do you expect? Someone at a computer who will call you if something goes wrong?

Comment: Well, i dont know, something looking if the value is the same as one of the values in the select form or something like that, i mean i'm the one who asked the question of course i don't know the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I write more info about your problem.

Usually what you need is called `whitelisting` - you create a list of some things, that are allowed for user.

It can be simple array like:

```
$allowed_options = ['op1','op2','op3'];
if (!in_array($userInput, $allowed_options)) {
    // input not allowed, do something
}
```

Or more complicated logic like a query to mysql:

```
select * from table where option = "USER_INPUT" and user_role = 'SOME_ROLE'
```

Anyway, only **you** as a developer **know** how to limit user's activity.

If, for example, you create your `select` from array of values:

```
foreach ($values as $v) {
    echo '<option value="' . $v . '">VALUE</option>";
}
```

Then **use same** array `$values` to check if user input is allowed.

Same to mysql queries or other ways of getting required content.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot ! My only problem is that i can't use "$_POST['validperso']" in my_array because it's a key, but i can work from here i guess, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your target better way you bind user with options in DB *(i.e. Like username and Password)* and then every time you validate user and options.

Another way you can put a hidden field with correct option and user mapped. And every time you can matched user selected option with hidden field value. This is not secure method.